# get diff between files in two different git repos and apply to first repo

Tags: linux, git, version-control, git-diff

I have two different local git repos, which we'll call `a` and `b`. They are both in a `projects` folder in my home directory. I want to get a diff between a particular file in both repos, let's call it `foo`, and apply that diff to `a`.

if I run `git diff ./foo ../b/foo > diff.diff` from inside `a` I can look at the diff and confirm that it contains the changes I want to apply, but when I run `git apply diff.diff` then I get this error:

```
fatal: invalid path './foo'
```

If I try running `git diff ~/projects/a/foo ~/projects/b/foo > diff.diff`, then when I try to apply the diff I get this error:

```
error: home/ryan/projects/a/foo: No such file or directory
```

Now, I can just copy the file to get the same effect as applying the diff, but is there a good reason why this isn't working?

Comment: You can only git diffs within a single repo. But you could run just regular `diff`. To use the output of `diff` to use with `git apply`, use `diff -u` for unidiff format.

Comment: I just tried that using relative paths, and it produced a diff successfully, but I got a similar `No such file or directory` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare `foo` file between repo `a` and repo `b` and apply the changes to repo `a`, you just need to use below commands:

```
# In ~/projects/a (local repo a)
git remote add repob  ~/projects/b -f
git diff master repob/master -- foo > diff.patch
git apply diff.patch
```

Now the `foo` in repo `a` change to the version of repo `b`. Then you can commit and push:

```
git add foo
git commit -m 'change foo as the version in repo b'
git push
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but that looks like it would just make a diff and commit the diff file itself to the repo. Does that actually apply the diff?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. Then it will actually apply the changes `foo` from repo `b` to repo `a`.

Comment: I find it odd that adding the remote is required but I tried that and it worked! This does leave the diff in the `a` directory, so one might want to use `/tmp/diff.patch` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `git diff` isn’t buying you anything here—you might as well use plain `diff -u`. The reason why the patch won’t apply is because `git-apply` is being confused by the inconsistent file paths in the diff. To fix this, you need to set your working directory so that the diff has relative paths in it of the same depth for both versions of the file. Here I change directory to the common parent of both project directories:

```
cd ~/projects
diff -u a/foo b/foo >a/diff.patch
cd a
patch -p1 <diff.patch
git add ... commit ... etc ...
```